# Sort 3 columns in different sort directions using Mongo Middleware

Tags: mongodb, middleware

When using Mongo Middleware, you can configure multiple columns for ascending / descending order as shown in the example

[You may also specify ascending and descending sorts together:](https://code.csdn.net/backendproject/mongoose-middleware)

```
var options = {
    sort : {
        asc : 'name'
        desc : ['birthday', 'home']
    }
};
```

The problem I wish to solve is how to have each column with its own configured sort direction.

The Middleware sort configuration only seems to support two configuration nodes (asc & desc).

There is no way to do something like the following.

```
var options = {
    sort : {
        name: 'asc',
        birthday: 'desc',
        home: asc
    }
};
```

Comment: According to their docs, "All descending sorts will be applied prior to ascending sorts when specifying multiple sorts of each direction." What you're trying to do is very much possible with MongoDB, but apparently not with this middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it would seem is that all you really need to do is call the normal [`.sort()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort) method from Mongoose instead of the [`.order()`](https://github.com/PlayNetwork/mongoose-middleware#sorting) method of the plugin:

```js
var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

require('mongoose-middleware').initialize(mongoose);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var testSchema = new Schema({
  a: Number,
  b: Number,
  c: Number
});

var Test = mongoose.model( 'Test', testSchema );

async.series(
  [
    function(callback) {
      Test.remove({},callback);
    },
    function(callback) {
      async.each(
        [
          { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 },
          { a: 2, b: 1, c: 4 },
          { a: 4, b: 3, c: 1 },
          { a: 2, b: 2, c: 1 }
        ],
        function(item,callback) {
          Test.create(item,callback);
        },
        callback
      );
    },

    function(callback) {
      Test.find().sort("a -b c").page({
        start: 0,
        count: 3
      },function(err,docs) {
        console.log(docs);
        callback(err);
      });
    }
  ],
  function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
);
```

Which returns the results affected by the middleware itself as per normal:

```js
{ options: { start: 0, count: 3 },
  results:
   [ { _id: 55da9c9593d2c4ed0d26cf79, a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, __v: 0 },
     { _id: 55da9c9593d2c4ed0d26cf7c, a: 2, b: 2, c: 1, __v: 0 },
     { _id: 55da9c9593d2c4ed0d26cf7a, a: 2, b: 1, c: 4, __v: 0 } ],
  total: 4 }
```

So the standard method for affecting the cursor seems to be the most appropriate to use in this case.

If you really want, then just put in something that reflects the pagination options into the configuration. It apparently does not matter unless the specific `.order()` method is actually called:

```js
var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

require('mongoose-middleware').initialize(mongoose);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var testSchema = new Schema({
  a: Number,
  b: Number,
  c: Number
});

var Test = mongoose.model( 'Test', testSchema );

async.series(
  [
    function(callback) {
      Test.remove({},callback);
    },
    function(callback) {
      async.each(
        [
          { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 },
          { a: 2, b: 1, c: 4 },
          { a: 4, b: 3, c: 1 },
          { a: 2, b: 2, c: 1 }
        ],
        function(item,callback) {
          Test.create(item,callback);
        },
        callback
      );
    },

    function(callback) {
      Test.find().sort({ a: 1, b: -1, c: 1 }).page({
        start: 0,
        count: 3,
        sort: {
          a: 1,
          b: -1,
          c: 1,
        }
      },function(err,docs) {
        console.log(docs);
        callback(err);
      });
    }
  ],
  function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
);
```

And the "options" are really just "dumped out":

```js
{ options: { start: 0, count: 3, sort: { a: 1, b: -1, c: 1 } },
  results:
   [ { _id: 55da9e12c74b0e0b0eeec3cf, a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, __v: 0 },
     { _id: 55da9e12c74b0e0b0eeec3d2, a: 2, b: 2, c: 1, __v: 0 },
     { _id: 55da9e12c74b0e0b0eeec3d0, a: 2, b: 1, c: 4, __v: 0 } ],
  total: 4 }
```

Where `{ a: 1, b: -1, c: 1 }` is a standard MongoDB form for a supported sort operation despite the extended syntax made available by mongoose. So it is still valid.

Comment: I will test that out later today, but that looks perfect, thanks for the detailed example, your a legend